Unique values in a ListBox from multiple tabs in Excel
I have one Excel Workbook with 3 tabs. In each tab there is a column with customers names.
How to make a multi-select ListBox on a Form that contains unique values from all 3 tabs at once?
So I do not want to have unique values from tab A + unique values from tab B + unique values from tab C because still I could have duplicates accross all 3 tabs. Is there a built-in function to solve this?

Use a Scripting.Dictionary to determine the unique items first.

Copy Distinct Values From Worksheets' Column to Array

Application
Sub DistinctValuesToListbox()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const DISPLAY_MESSAGE As Boolean = True
    ' The following two must have the same number of items!
    Dim WORKSHEET_NAMES() As Variant: WORKSHEET_NAMES = Array( _
        "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    Dim FIRST_CELL_ADDRESSES() As Variant: FIRST_CELL_ADDRESSES = Array( _
        "A2", "B2", "C2")
        
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Return the distinct values in a zero-based array.
    Dim DistinctValues As Variant:
    DistinctValues = DistinctFromWorksheetsColumnToArray( _
        wb, WORKSHEET_NAMES, FIRST_CELL_ADDRESSES, DISPLAY_MESSAGE)
    
    ' Check if no values (clear list box?).
    If IsEmpty(DistinctValues) Then
        'myListbox.Clear
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' For a small amount of data, test with a message box.
    MsgBox Join(DistinctValues, ", "), vbInformation
    
    ' Populate list box, e.g.:
    'myListbox.List = DistinctValues
 
End Sub

The Helper Function
Function DistinctFromWorksheetsColumnToArray( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    WorksheetNames As Variant, _
    FirstCellAddresses As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal DisplayMessage As Boolean = False) _
As Variant
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = _
        "Copy Distinct Values From Worksheets' Column to Array"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, Data() As Variant, Value As Variant
    Dim rCount As Long, r As Long, n As Long, IsNoDataFound As Boolean
    
    For n = LBound(WorksheetNames) To UBound(WorksheetNames)
        On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets(WorksheetNames(n))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then ' worksheet exists
            With ws.Range(FirstCellAddresses(n))
                rCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column) _
                    .End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
                Select Case rCount
                    Case Is < 1: IsNoDataFound = True
                    Case 1: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data = .Value
                    Case Else: Data = .Resize(rCount).Value
                End Select
            End With
            If IsNoDataFound Then ' no data found
                IsNoDataFound = False ' reset
            Else ' data found
                For r = 1 To rCount
                    Value = Data(r, 1)
                    If Not IsError(Value) Then
                        Value = CStr(Value)
                        If Len(Value) > 0 Then
                            If Not dict.Exists(Value) Then dict(Value) = Empty
                        End If
                    End If
                Next r
            End If
            Set ws = Nothing ' reset
        'Else ' worksheet doesn't exist i.e. 'ws Is Nothing'
        End If
    Next n
            
    If dict.Count = 0 Then
        If DisplayMessage Then
            MsgBox "No distinct values found!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    DistinctFromWorksheetsColumnToArray = dict.Keys
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

